# How to merge two array of objects in angular?

Tags: javascript

```js
arr1 = [{
  name: "jen",
  age: 25,
  degree: "master"
}, {
  name: "dali",
  age: 20,
  degree: "bachelor"
}];
arr2 = [{
  year: 2015,
  city: "xxx"
}];
```

I need the array like this

**result**

```js
[{
  name: "jen",
  age: 25,
  degree: "master",
  year: 2015,
  city: "xxx"
}, {
  name: "dali",
  age: 20,
  degree: "bachelor",
  year: 2015,
  city: "xxx"
}];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is expected that you show your attempts to solve your own issue. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the spread `...` operator along with `map` to iterate/merge.

```js
const arr1 = [{
  name: "jen",
  age: 25,
  degree: "master"
}, {
  name: "dali",
  age: 20,
  degree: "bachelor"
}];
const arr2 = [{
  year: 2015,
  city: "xxx"
}];


const mergedArray = arr1.map(i => ({ ...i,
  ...arr2[0]
}));
console.log(mergedArray);
```

- [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: It's not working

Comment: You need to provide more details in your question then. Try providing your current code attempt.

Comment: ya bro. Its working fine. Thanks for your help